# How can I remove VMWare Player?

Tags: 18.04, vmware, vmware-player

The `vmware-installer` command isn't found. Perhaps someone could send me their `vmware-installer` binary? It isn't an apt or snap app.

```
vmware-installer: command not found
```

Comment: Thanks, I ran that and found the uninstaller.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  I converted the comment to an answer so you can accept it and mark the issue as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it's not present on the system but with another name? Run `sudo find / -iname '*vmware-installer*' -type f` and once you find the installer, you will need to run that file with `sudo` and execute the uninstall task of the VMware Installer.

Since VMware Player isn't installed via snap or apt, it has to be removed with the VMware script.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [Stacer](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/stacer). It has a good option for removing apt packages and snap apps.

Comment: VMWare Player isn't installed via snaps or apt packages.